# Laravel Develoyment on AWS EC2 server

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, deployment

This is the virtualhost configuration.  This is not working. please help me

```sh
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog/public

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/blog/>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: have you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/deployment)? Also, read the logs. The laravel logs, not nginx logs

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what exactly `is not working`.

Comment: This page isn’t working

HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

most common case after deployment is proper permissions. `storage` and `bootstrap` should have writeable permissions.

if the problem not about permissions then check the logs of laravel
`storage/logs/laravel.log`